# Mpmoviepalyer exit full screen misplacing the container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to paly video in a horizonatl collection view where i have a holder view for MPMoviePlayerController and a text view for description(using xib for this 2 views to add in collection view flow layout).While rotating to landscape mode making MPMoviePlayerController as full screen,and it will be in full screen mode(irrespective of orientation) until i press the exit full screen button.

Now the issue arises,when i press the exit full screen button,the collection view is shifting to left down corner.